# Plotting an ROC curve in glmnet

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, roc, glmnet

**EDIT: As Dwin pointed out in the comments, the code below is not for an ROC curve. An ROC curve must be indexed in variation in `t` and not in `lambda` (as I do below). I will edit the code below when I get the chance.**

Below is my attempt to create an ROC curve of glmnet predicting a binary outcome. I've simulated a matrix that approximates glmnet results in the code below. As some of you know, given an *n* x *p* matrix of inputs, glmnet outputs an *n* x 100 matrix of predicted probabilities [$\Pr(y_i = 1)$] for 100 different values of lambda. The output will be narrower than 100 if further changes in lambda stop increasing predictive power. The simulated matrix of glmnet predicted probabilities below is a 250x69 matrix.

**First, is there an easier way to plot a glmnet ROC curve? Second, if not, does the below approach seem correct? Third, do I care about plotting (1) the probability of false/true positives OR (2) simply the observed rate of false/true positives?**

```
set.seed(06511)

# Simulate predictions matrix
phat = as.matrix(rnorm(250,mean=0.35, sd = 0.12))
lambda_effect = as.matrix(seq(from = 1.01, to = 1.35, by = 0.005))
phat = phat %*% t(lambda_effect)


#Choose a cut-point
t = 0.5

#Define a predictions matrix
predictions = ifelse(phat >= t, 1, 0)

##Simulate y matrix
y_phat = apply(phat, 1, mean) + rnorm(250,0.05,0.10)
y_obs = ifelse(y_phat >= 0.55, 1, 0)

#percentage of 1 observations in the validation set, 
p = length(which(y_obs==1))/length(y_obs)

#   dim(testframe2_e2)

#probability of the model predicting 1 while the true value of the observation is 0, 
apply(predictions, 1, sum)

## Count false positives for each model
## False pos ==1, correct == 0, false neg == -1
error_mat = predictions - y_obs
## Define a matrix that isolates false positives
error_mat_fp = ifelse(error_mat ==1, 1, 0)
false_pos_rate = apply(error_mat_fp, 2,  sum)/length(y_obs)

# Count true positives for each model
## True pos == 2, mistakes == 1, true neg == 0
error_mat2 = predictions + y_obs
## Isolate true positives
error_mat_tp = ifelse(error_mat2 ==2, 1, 0)
true_pos_rate = apply(error_mat_tp, 2,  sum)/length(y_obs)


## Do I care about (1) this probability OR (2) simply the observed rate?
## (1)
#probability of false-positive, 
p_fp = false_pos_rate/(1-p)
#probability of true-positive, 
p_tp = true_pos_rate/p

#plot the ROC, 
plot(p_fp, p_tp)


## (2)
plot(false_pos_rate, true_pos_rate)
```

There's one question on this on SO, but the answer was rough and not quite right: [glmnet lasso ROC charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362974/glmnet-lasso-roc-charts/11462169#11462169)

Comment: The plot of accuracy of prediction as a function of lambda is NOT an "ROC curve".

Comment: @DWin Are you saying that it's only really an "ROC curve" if the input we vary is the discrimination threshold, here `t`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what he's saying.

Comment: For one thing an ROC curve is monotonic while the curve (to which i do not see a name given in my references) you are describing is not, at least if it is on the OOB or validation data.

Comment: @HongOoi +1 and DWin +1 Thanks for pointing that out. I will edit the question accordingly. I'm still stuck with the fundamental question though, how to output an ROC curve from glmnet results. Also, why couldn't I plot FPR against TPR across values of lambda to choose a lambda? It's not an ROC curve, but wouldn't it still be useful?

Comment: I ran this code and was surprised to see jointly rising FPR and FNR. I must not understand what these are measuring. Wouldn't these be expected to have a reciprocal relationship?

Comment: TPR/FPR on ROC represents the likelihood of getting true pos at a particular probabilistic threshold, so any lambda will have a full spectrum of probabilities from 0 to 1 on a ROC. You could look at area under curve for different lambdas, which essentially summarizes how much more likely your model will produce TPR than FPR.

Answer (score 8):

An option that uses `ROCR` to calculate AUC & plot ROC curve:

```
library(ROCR)
library(glmnet)
library(caret)

df <- data.matrix(… ) # dataframe w/ predictor variables & a response variable
                      # col1 = response var; # cols 2:10 = predictor vars

# Create training subset for model development & testing set for model performance testing
inTrain <- createDataPartition(df$ResponsVar, p = .75, list = FALSE)
Train <- df[ inTrain, ]
Test <- df[ -inTrain, ]

# Run model over training dataset
lasso.model <- cv.glmnet(x = Train[,2:10], y = Train[,1], 
                         family = 'binomial', type.measure = 'auc')

# Apply model to testing dataset
Test$lasso.prob <- predict(lasso.model,type="response", 
                           newx = Test[,2:10], s = 'lambda.min')
pred <- prediction(Test$lasso.prob, Test$ResponseVar)

# calculate probabilities for TPR/FPR for predictions
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
performance(pred,"auc") # shows calculated AUC for model
plot(perf,colorize=FALSE, col="black") # plot ROC curve
lines(c(0,1),c(0,1),col = "gray", lty = 4 )
```

For the `Test$lasso.prob` above, you could enter different lambdas to test the predictive power at each value.

Answer (score 0):

With predictions and labels, here's how to create a basic ROC curve

```
# randomly generated data for example, binary outcome
predictions = runif(100, min=0, max=1) 
labels = as.numeric(predictions > 0.5) 
labels[1:10] = abs(labels[1:10] - 1) # randomly make some labels not match predictions

# source: https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/08/roc-curves-in-two-lines-of-code.html
labels_reordered = labels[order(predictions, decreasing=TRUE)]
roc_dat = data.frame(TPR=cumsum(labels_reordered)/sum(labels_reordered), FPR=cumsum(!labels_reordered)/sum(!labels_reordered))

# plot the roc curve
plot(roc_dat$FPR, roc_dat$TPR)
```

[generated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h63P0.png)